# ASP.NET MVC3, Flash slider with XML Config referencing image paths

Tags: xml, flash, asp.net-mvc-3, filepath

I'm trying to use flashmo image slider with ASP.NET MVC3 but run into an issue with the XML configuration file for the Flash slider...the XML file uses a direct path to the photos I want to use..for instance:

```
<photo>
    <filename>./photos/slider_4_text.jpg</filename>
    <description><![CDATA[<p class="subtitle">Photo title four goes here</p><p>Mauris vestibulum felis eget tortor. <a href="http://www.flashmo.com" target="_blank">Praesent mattis varius quam</a>. Vestibulum ullamcorper ipsum nec augue. Vestibulum auctor odio eget ante. <span class="highlight">Nunc commodo, magna pharetra semper vehicula, dui ligula feugiat elit, et euismod nunc orci ut libero.</span></p>]]></description>
    <transition sequence="first" direction="down" slice="9" effect="easeInOutQuart"></transition>
</photo>
```

I've checked out the other question which is similar to mine (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116732/flash-xml-config-file-problems-with-asp-net-mvc) but I feel like this doesn't directly apply to my situation.

Can anyone lend a hand on exactly how to point my XML config file to the proper location of my images?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just switched to the jQuery-powered [EasySlider](http://cssglobe.com/post/5780/easy-slider-17-numeric-navigation-jquery-slider).

But if anyone wants to know a workaround for the issue stated in this question, you can just reference the content directly in the XML file from the web root..for example /Content/Themes/red/images/image_1.xml.